# White list S3 resources by extensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Struggling to create a bucket policy to white list certain file types. Specifically, I want to allow only image types to be accessible.

I was able to create a blacklist policy like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[my_bucket]/*.exe"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**WHITELIST ATTEMPT #1:**

Problem: this allows all types, not just those listed

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[my_bucket]/*.jpg",
        "arn:aws:s3:::[my_bucket]/*.png",
        "arn:aws:s3:::[my_bucket]/*.gif",
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**WHITELIST ATTEMPT #2:**

Problem: this ends up denying all files

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::[my_bucket]/*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      }
    },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[my_bucket]/*.jpg",
        "arn:aws:s3:::[my_bucket]/*.png",
        "arn:aws:s3:::[my_bucket]/*.gif",
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: **Any** matching deny always denies.  An allow cannot overrule a deny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whitelist bucket policy #1 is correct. The reason it is allowing all file types **could be your IAM policy allows all file types** for the user. Make sure the IAM policy attached to the user does not have **S3FullAccess**

> In accordance with the principle of least-privilege, decisions default
>   to DENY and an explicit DENY always trumps an ALLOW. For example, if
>   an IAM policy grants access to an object, the S3 bucket policies
>   denies access to that object, and there is no S3 ACL, then access will
>   be denied. Similarly, if no method specifies an ALLOW, then the
>   request will be denied by default. Only if no method specifies a DENY
>   and one or more methods specify an ALLOW will the request will be
>   allowed.

Comment: Thanks @helloV - I didn't have an IAM applied, but turns out I was assigning 'public-read' ACLs at the object level, which was overriding the policy.